# Capture *all* events of a given type, regardless of bubble/target

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events

I'm writing a Chrome extension that needs to be notified of **all** `click` and `keyup` events, regardless of whether `stopPropagation`/etc was called in consuming code.  This means that `document.addEventListener` is off the table.

I have tried the following:

### Attempt 1: Hook into `addEventListener`

```js
const _addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(eventName, eventHandler) {
    console.log('DOM Event', eventName);
    _addEventListener.call(this, eventName, eventHandler);
};
```

### Attempt 2: Hook into `stopPropagation`

```js
const _stopPropagation = Event.prototype.stopPropagation;
Event.prototype.stopPropagation = function() {
    console.log('Stop Propagation:', this);
    return _mouseEvent.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

### Attempt 3: Hook into even constructors

```js
const _mouseEvent = MouseEvent;
MouseEvent = function() {
    console.log('Mouse Event:', this);
    return _mouseEvent.apply(this, arguments);
};

const _keyboardEvent = KeyboardEvent;
KeyboardEvent = function() {
    console.log('Keyboard Event:', this);
    return _keyboardEvent.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

As a last resort I could add my own `click` event listener on **every** DOM element—but that just seems like a ton of overhead for something that seems like it should be doable.

Anyone know of a viable option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gah, I don't know how I forgot about `useCapture`.  This works:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {}, true /* <--- this */);
```